# Format Java Code into Word / RTF

Tags: java, formatting, ms-word

I need to format java code to put into a Word document.  Are there any programs that will do this with keyword highlighting, etc. ?

Answer (score 3):

When I copy/paste from my IDE (Eclipse), the formatting comes along for the ride.

You'll probably want to turn off "Mark Occurrences" first.

Comment: AND the cute little colors (usually).  They even show up in Outlook.

Comment: Hm.  It doesn't seem to work for me, but I'm on OS X.  I will have to try it on Windows.

Ideally I'd like something that can do it for an entire project so I don't have to copy and paste every single file.  Any suggestions there?

Answer (score 1):

This is a late reply but since it's quite a specific requirement I'll post my comment anyway.

You can do this programmatically with [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) assuming you want the program to be running in Java (not just showing java in documents) and can install OpenOffice where the program runs.  The process would be:

1. Create a doc or odt file that will
   act as a template (setting fonts,
   position, tables etc) and will have
   a placeholder for where you want to
   insert the code sample
2. Add docmosis to your java project
   and write the code to initialise
   Docmosis, register the template,
   then render document with your
   selected Java code.
3. Currently, Docmosis FieldRenderers
   can underline or italicize your data
   as it goes, but the rendering is
   currently applied to the entire
   field.  So this wouldn't let you
   have a single field for all your
   java text and individually highlight
   words, but there are a few other
   tricks that you could employ to get
   useful/interesting results (such as
   splitting your data into separate
   fields and letting Docmosis render
   the fields differently).

The "java code" text that you specify as data will be inserted into your template using the font and layout properties in the template.  The renderer will have a chance to override specific formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy and then paste it to the word document. I am using OS X as well. I just works fine. I am uploading the screenshot of how it looks in word.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Easy Code Formatter](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104382008?tab=Overview) as called out here: [How do you display code snippets in MS Word preserving format and syntax highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387453/how-do-you-display-code-snippets-in-ms-word-preserving-format-and-syntax-highlig)

It's an Office add-in. You can select multiple themes, enable / disable line numbering / highlight lines in rectangles. It allows you to select the coding style / and has a quick formatting button. Pretty neat.

**Requires you to have Office 2013 or beyond.**

[image]