# Any templates for MS Word for formatting source code (when writing pseudocode)?

Tags: ide, code-formatting

I'm writing an interface spec in MS Word and it would be great if there were some sort of template or pluggin for Word (2003 here) that would make it all look a bit prettier.

(I'm realizing how spoiled I am with even the archaic VB6 IDE).

Comment: Check these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252098/what-is-the-best-way-to-insert-source-code-examples-into-a-microsoft-word-docume http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387453/how-do-you-display-code-snippets-in-ms-word-preserving-format-and-syntax-highlig http://superuser.com/questions/419814/create-a-microsoft-word-quick-style-for-a-code-snippet-box