# How to export syntax highlighted RMarkdown code to PDF?

Tags: r, r-markdown

For a thesis, I would like to attach the *code* (not the output) of my .Rmd document, ideally with the pretty syntax highlighting that RStudio does.

Is there a way to export highlighted RMarkdown code to a file, ideally PDF?

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128702/how-to-preserve-formatting-from-rstudio-when-copy-pasting-to-word

Answer (score 1):

I would check this out.

http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#appearance_and_style

I think it should be as simple as

```
---
title: "Habits"
output:
  pdf_document:
    highlight: tango
---
```