# Putting code just like in the forum in microsoft word

Tags: ms-word

I am doing my coursework and I want to put the queries in code format in microsoft word. Just like in the forums. Is it possible?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387453/how-do-you-display-code-snippets-in-ms-word-preserving-format-and-syntax-highlig

Comment: Yes, it is indeed possible.