# transferring python text into word document

Tags: python

When looking at my code in the python file, it is lovely and colourful, however these colours do not carry over when putting it into a word document (microsoft). Is there anyway to do this without screenshots or do I have to suffer.

Comment: Look up the Code Format Add in for Word.

Comment: Code in a file is bits, which have no color.  The color is coming from your IDE or editor.  Loading the source into Word does not have any way to determine the colors since the IDE is not involved.  Try copy/paste.

Comment: If copying and pasting from your IDE doesn't work, you could always [use Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/578054/how-can-i-copy-text-with-syntax-highlighting-from-notepad) to preserve syntax highlighting.

Comment: Here is a link to a similar question. Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387453/how-do-you-display-code-snippets-in-ms-word-preserving-format-and-syntax-highlig

Comment: See http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/. After making it into html I think copy paste will do.