# How to get the text marked with PostgreSQL colours when you copy the code to Word?

Tags: postgresql

The point is that I want to copy the piece of code to the Word doc, and the result is that I get the text that is unmarked with colours.
How can I get the same text - with violet, orange, green, etc. colours like in PostgeSQL (PGAdmin4)?

Comment: PostgresQL doesn't colour text. What are you talking about?

Comment: Postgres is a database server that has no UI and that does not display any result with colours. If you see some coloured output, it's the _tool_ you are using to display query result that does that, it's **not** PostgreSQL.

Comment: How's that? When I type SELECT - the colour of this word is violet, numbers are orange, etc. I'm talking about a query syntax colouring, it's not about output.

Comment: You can find answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387453/how-do-you-display-code-snippets-in-ms-word-preserving-format-and-syntax-highlig

Comment: **Postgres is not PGAdmin4** they are very different things. PGAdmin4 is an app that provides a GUI to the PostgreSQL database server. It is the app that handles the colorization.

Comment: I agree, sorry for the unaccuracy. I meant PGAdmin4