# Is there a way to copy paste text from Python IDLE in color?

Tags: python-idle

I spent weeks on learning and writing scripts. I'm attaching some to resumé, however I want it copy pasted in color to make it look nice. I'm using Microsoft Word for my resumé files. is there a way to copy paste the IDLE text in color?

Comment: IDLE editor windows are python tkinter and hence  tcl tk text windows.  I searched pypi.org for 'tk text to odt' and the first 20 hits were either tk or odt related (such as pdf2odt) but not both.  There is a python odt library, so someone could write a converter for tkinter text and odt in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you display code snippets in MS Word preserving format and syntax highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387453/how-do-you-display-code-snippets-in-ms-word-preserving-format-and-syntax-highlig)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering, we can use OpenDocumentText in Microsoft Word which retains the color and formatting of the code with a simple copy paste

[Steps to copy paste code for presentations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387453/how-do-you-display-code-snippets-in-ms-word-preserving-format-and-syntax-highlig)

Comment: This should be edited into the question.