# Is there any way to make a word macro to automatically format pasted text into the document font?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a way to automatically change copy-pasted text into the document default font and font size. This needs to be document based. Basically, a client doesn't want to do anything more than copy-paste into the template document, no changing Word settings or nothing. Is there any way to do this?

Here's some code I had so far (with help from ChatGPT) that doesn't work at all but was supposed to set up an application event handler that fires every time the selection changes (e.g. clicking or pasting). This was obviously a bad approach but I had no other ideas and am very new to VBA.

```
Private WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Set App = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sel.Range
    
    If rng.Start <> rng.End Then
        rng.Font.Name = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font.Name
        
        rng.Font.Size = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font.Size
        
    End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify 'doesn't really work' ... do you get an error (which error number and text and on which line) or does the code do nothing or something else ... please be specific.

Comment: Sorry, should've been more specific. It doesn't work at all. No errors or anything, nothing happens.

Comment: Tell your client to learn to use Word correctly. Using code as a workaround for their sheer laziness would be idiotic.  There are settings under File | Options that determine default paste settings. There is also a paste options tool that appears immediately after pasting, unless they've turned it off. The Merge Formatting option is the one they should use, keyboard shortcut - Ctrl, M

Comment: The code needs to be in the `ThisDocument` module and won't work if you have put it anywhere else. The code does work but you will need to close and re-open the document first. Then format some text with the 'wrong' font name or size then move the cursor away and then back to select it. However, @TimothyRylatt does have a point ...

Comment: I know, I also think it's ridiculous and have told my boss the same with step-by-step instructions to show how to use Word like a normal person, unfortunately I was told to do it this way anyway.

Comment: Using `App_WindowSelectionChange` means that code will run every time the insertion point changes, i.e. every time they type a character, that code will run. Every time they attempt to apply bold, or italic, or any other formatting option the code will override their action. As there isn't an event to only capture pasting you would need to write a custom paste routine and force the client to use that. Best of luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Option:
   Take the clients computer
   Open Word - goto Options and Advanced
   Then in the part of cut copy paste change the defaults to Merge formatting or keep text (I guess you could do this also by some code in the registry)
   Than take 100000 $ from the client :-)

2.Option
Write code, that will hook everything, what could paste. Shortcuts, Menu, Ribbon, ... and I guess you can ask for 10000000$ :-)
Perhaps somewhere in the API Bible exists and SendMessage for Pasting but I doubt it for all ways of pasting.

3.Option
Go with Timothy' first answer

Comment: Although I think this should be a comment. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider for implementing this solution. I am explaining it step by step for those new to VBA macro. I am not a VBA developer but a C# .net developer and have developed this solution using chat GPT and MSDN documentation and with lots of hit and try, so there is a possibility that this code requires optimisation. I have also created a VBA script that performs some more functions for copy paste in Word you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78129163/how-can-i-remove-the-background-color-of-copied-text-color-formatted-during-pa/78130643#78130643)

**Step-1:** Open a new Word document and save it as *.docm (macro enabled word document). I have given the filename as 'MyAutoFormatMacro.docm'

[image]

**Step-2:** Enable Developer option from File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Developer (checkbox)
[image]

**Step-3:** Enable Macro from File > Options > Trust Centre > Macro Settings > Enable all macero (radio button)
[image]

**Step-4:** Modify the default font name and font size from  Home > Style
[image]

**Step-5:** Open VBA script module inside `ThisDocument` from Developer > VisalBasic > Project (Your word document file name) > ThisDocument (double click)

[image]

**Step-6:** Paste the below VBA script inside `ThisDocument`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_Open()
    With Application.KeyBindings.Add(WdKeyCategory.wdKeyCategoryCommand, "PasteAndFormatText", BuildKeyCode(WdKey.wdKeyControl, WdKey.wdKeyV))
    
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub Document_Close()
' Reset the CTRL+V key combination when the document is closed
    Application.KeyBindings.ClearAll
End Sub


Sub PasteAndFormatText()
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim startPos As Long
    
    ' Store the start position
    startPos = Selection.Start
    
    ' Paste the content from the clipboard
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
    
    ' Extend the selection from the start position to the current selection end
    Selection.SetRange Start:=startPos, End:=Selection.End
    
    ' Now, with the pasted content selected, change its formatting
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font.Name   ' Change font name as needed
        .Size = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font.Size ' Change font size as needed
    End With
    
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

**Step-7:** Click `save` on the VBA window to save the script and then Close the VBA app window and close the Word document, you will be prompted to save the document. click save.

[image]

**Step-8:** Now again open the Word document that we saved in the previous step and try to copy some formatted colour text of different fonts and sizes, now when you press Ctrl+V on the Word document your text should be automatically changed to your default font and size.

**Output: **hurray!!****

[image]